# change white cell border color in chart.js

Tags: css, chart.js

how can i change the cell border color in chart.js. i searched in the docs but there is no option for this.
[chart.js color docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html?h=bordercolor)

i have a dark and a light theme in my vue app and i want to change the color depending on which theme is selected

cell border should be white if dark mode is on and should be white when light mode is on.

its a simple thing and i really don't want to sit on that for a day or two. maybe someone knows how to solve this.

Comment: Add some code dude, noone will help you like this.

Answer (score 0):

for all who didn't  found it in the docs like me.

the option is called:

```js
    this.options = {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            gridLines: {
              color: '#000000'
            }
          }
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            gridLines: {
              color: '#000000'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

can be found here:
[gridLines](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html?h=gridlines)